# Функция len выдает ошибку

Tags: python-3.x

```
message = input("Введите текст: ")
print("\nДлина введенного вами текста составляет:". len(message))
```

Выводит ошибку.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'
```

Comment: Увидел. Исправил . Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
message = input("Введите текст: ")
print("\nДлина введенного вами текста составляет:". len(message))
```

Ошибка в «.» (точке), вместо точки нужна «,» (запятая).

Исправлена версия

```
message = input("Введите текст: ")
print("\nДлина введенного вами текста составляет:", len(message))
```